# Не знаю как правильно отправить запрос Java Android

Tags: java, android

Начал программировать под андроид. Не профи но легкие приложения получаются.

Проблема в том что у меня задача написать приложения "Рекламы" где будут выкладывать свои товары. В идеале клиент должен отправить `POST` запрос на сервер, в ответ придет строка, из которой я получаю данные и на их основе строю страницу товаров.

Помогите советом на правильный ли метод я полагаюсь и вообще как сделать запрос серверу (Желательно без сторонних библиотек)

Comment: Без сторонних библиотек -- нежелательно. Смотрите в сторону, например, OkHttp, Retrofit, Jsoup. Смотря что Вам бекэнд отдает.

Comment: а данные пересылать в формате JSON

Comment: aQuery удобная библиотека

Comment: Скорее всего JSON что посоветуете?

Answer (score 0):

Напиши API для своего сервера и отправляй ему запросы, а дальше обрабатывай ответы на стороне приложения и строй страницу товара. Ещё стоит поработать с БД.

Comment: проблема в том что я не умею отправлять простые http запросы если бы увидел бы пример. Спасибо